# Can you use the current font size as a metric for other properties?

Tags: swiftui

Pretty simple question.  I have a custom geometry-based shape that I want to utilize the current (i.e. default) font size to determine calculations for its rendering.  For instance, if the font size is 12, I want the corner radius to be 1/4 that side, or three.  But I'm not sure how to get the current font's metrics.  Is it possible?

The reasoning is my control has a text component.  If someone applies a font to it and changes the size as a result, I want to update my geometry to match that new size.  So is it possible?

Comment: Would using Environment Value `.dynamicTypeSize` help to make your computations? The font would be defined by you, the only thing that the user can control is the dynamic size, so knowing it hopefully you can come up with a way to compute your desired corner radius

Comment: You can't get the typography of the font but you ca get the View size or use ScaledMetric

Comment: Yeah, I went with ScaledMetric for some, then just created a new, custom view that used percentages instead of actual units, then I calculated it that way. Not perfect, but a pretty good facsimile for my ultimate needs.

Comment: @loremipsum, looks like this is the best answer.  Wanna move it to an *actual* answer so I can mark it as such? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the typography of the font but you can get the View size or use `ScaledMetric`

```
import SwiftUI

struct FontSizeView: View {
    //Use the View's size
    @State var textSize: CGSize = .zero
    //Apple's solution to adjusting views using the font size as a reference
    @ScaledMetric var subViewSize: CGFloat = 48
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Hello, World!")
                .modifier(ViewSizeViewModifier(size: $textSize))
            Circle()
                .frame(width: subViewSize, height: subViewSize)
        }
    }
}

struct ViewSizeViewModifier: ViewModifier{
    @Binding var size: CGSize
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .background(
                GeometryReader{ proxy in
                    Color.clear
                        .onAppear(){
                            //initial value
                            size = proxy.size
                        }.onChange(of: proxy.size) { newValue in
                            //Updates with changes to orientation and such.
                            size = newValue
                        }
                }
            )
    }
}
```